# Is it possible to apply commands to specific pages (the first page)

Tags: titles, two-column, revtex

Tricky question (for me at least!) I am using `revtex` which allows you to switch between a one and two column environment using the `\onecolumngrid` and `\twocolumngrid` commands.

I would like my first page to be one column and then subsequent pages two column. Is there any way to avoid tediously moving the position of `\twocolumngrid` every time I make changes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 2):

At a paragraph end TeX breaks the paragraph into lines with the current settings including the line width. The result are horizontal boxes that are placed on the pages and page breaks are inserted if necessary. The change from one column to two column layout very likely also changes the line width. Thus any left over lines from a paragraph of the first page would not fit into the smaller column of the second page any more. TeX does not provide any way back from the horizontal line boxes to the text that had generated the lines.

The workaround to avoid this situation is to add a manual page break:

- `\newpage` and similar
- Something like

  ```
  {\setlength{parfillskip}{0pt}\par\newpage}\noindent
  ```

  inside a paragraph to manually split the paragraph for the page break
  and making the split "invisible".